# Is it Possible to link the tablix from charts in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a Report which has three tables .Each table is made visible based on the parameters.Now i am planning to add charts to the reports for Visualization.So, is it possible to link the added charts to the specific Table?
I mean when i click on the chart item will that redirect me to the specific table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may not get the precision you're looking for, but you can definitely implement this general type of functionality via the use of Bookmarks or Document Maps:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239378.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239329.aspx